# DateTime conversion: "The timezone could not be found in the database"

Tags: php, datetime

I'm trying to convert a DateTime that I'm receiving from an API.

This is how their are generating the datetime string:

```
public static function formatDate($date) {
    $format = "Y-m-d\TH:i:sP";
    if ($date instanceof DateTime) {
        $d = $date->format($format);
    } elseif (is_numeric($date)) {
        $d = date($format, $date);
    } else {
        $d = (String) "$date";
    }
    return $d;
}
```

Wich gives me

```
 "2013-06-14T04:00:36.000-03:00"
```

And this is what I am doing to convert it back:

```
try 
{ 
   $date = Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat("Y-m-d\TH:i:sP", "2013-06-14T04:00:36-03:00");

   echo "<pre>".var_dump($date)."</pre>";

   $date = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d\TH:i:sP", "2013-06-14T04:00:36.000-03:00");

   echo "<pre>".var_dump($date)."</pre>";

   $date = Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat("Y-m-d\TH:i:sP", "2013-06-14T04:00:36.000-03:00"); /// raise exception

   echo "<pre>".var_dump($date)."</pre>";
} 
catch(InvalidArgumentException $x) 
{ 
    echo $x->getMessage(); 
}
```

DateTime class gives me just a null, no errors, but Carbon (https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon) extended from DateTime tells me what's happening and this is the ouput:

```
object(Carbon\Carbon)#181 (3) { ["date"]=> string(19) "2013-06-14 04:00:36" ["timezone_type"]=> int(1) ["timezone"]=> string(6) "-03:00" }

bool(false)

The timezone could not be found in the database
```

So, just dropping the ".000" from the datetime it works, but why, if it was created by PHP using the exact same format I'm using to convert it back?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is not the same format. Proper format for a string that you are receiving is:

```
$format = "Y-m-d\TH:i:s.uP";
```